# Alternatives to Ushahidi for Crowdsourcing?

Tags: open-source-gis, web-gis, crowdsourcing, ushahidi

We all know that [Ushahidi](http://www.ushahidi.com/) offers a versatile solution for crowdsourcing information and its effective depiction in maps.

I am interested to know if there is any application(free and open source) on par with or superior to Ushahidi!

I would be using the application to collect data from users via tweets, web forms, emails, SMS and map them using the location information provided by them; all of which can be accomplished by Ushahidi.

My deployment would be a permanent online deployment to collect ongoing information and not the one which would be live for few days/weeks.

Hence, one of the major limitation I foresee with Ushahidi is the requirement of manual intervention for approval of reports, which may need more personnel in the event of large number of responses.

Is there any possibility to build a custom solution for such purpose using different open source tools?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Have a look at [Open Data Kit](http://opendatakit.org/). Open source and free. Actively [used](http://opendatakit.org/about/deployments/). With [science](http://opendatakit.org/about/research/) behind.
- [i2maps](http://ncg.nuim.ie/i2maps/docs/) from [NCG](http://ncg.nuim.ie/) might be another option. In [examples](http://ncg.nuim.ie/i2maps/docs/index.php?page=examples) section of their website you will find [Twitter Trends](http://ncg.nuim.ie/i2maps/projects/twitter/index.html) and  [Real-Time Twitter](http://ncg.nuim.ie/i2maps/projects/tweets/index.html) apps.
- Forthcoming [gemma](http://gemma.casa.ucl.ac.uk/) project from CASA @ UCL [promises](http://gemma.blogs.casa.ucl.ac.uk/2011/02/hello-world/) to be another alternative.

Comment: Open Data Kit does not seem to be a solution to what I have been looking for. ODK largely eases out the information collection process through mobile devices. But I am looking for something which can accept data from social media/web as a whole.